# Set bottom navbar menu on the bottom of the page without a position:fixed (bootstrap, css3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to change my css so that the page has the bottom menu stay there (like fixed) but without the position:fixed.

Why?

Indeed, using Boostrap 3, I am using navbar-fixed-bottom .

BUT position:fixed [is not supported at all](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed) on Opera Mini which accounts for 10% almost of mobile browsers (see [here](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1&qpcustomb=1)).

**how can I create this without position:fixed ?**

3 constraints:

- I never want any scroll: it means if the viewport gets smaller(no matter the size of the viewport: big, small, desktop, tablet...), the menu and image will just get smaller and never any horizontal nor vertical scrollbar.
- and I want the menu to stay below the image (the quality of the image, distorted or not, is not my point in this question).
- i want only html and css: no javascript nor jquery. thanks

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

[image]

Here is my current code using fixed position:

```
<div>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"> 
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Title -->
            <div class="navbar-bottom pull-left">
              <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">BIGGA</a>
            </div>

            <!-- The non-Collapsing items on navbar-LEFT  -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
                <!-- pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                  <li>
                    <a href="/news">News</a> 
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- 'Sticky' (non-collapsing) right-side menu item(s) -->
            <div class="navbar-bottom pull-right">
                <ul class="nav pull-left">
                    <!-- This works well for static text, like a username -->
                    <li class="navbar-text pull-left">User Name</li>
                    <!-- Add any additional bootstrap header items. This is a drop-down from an icon -->
                    <li class="dropup pull-right"> <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#777; margin-top: 5px;" class="dropdow-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li> <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
            </div>                     


            <!-- Additional navbar items on the LEFT of the PULL-RIGHT stuff above -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <!-- pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="/locator">Locator</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/extras">Extras</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you `position:absolute` to the bottom of the container?

Comment: @slime seems to work but then many articles warn about pitfalls of absolute positionning ex: http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/. If I only have 2 divs (the image and then the menu, would that be ok to use absolute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an idea, about how it could be solved.

Use 2 divs, one after the other. The 1st div will contain your image, or whatever you want to put in the main content area. Its height is 90%, of course you can change or modify that. The second div is your menubar, the height is 10%, modify it as per your needs. Notice the `overflow:auto` in the .image_content class, it will contain your main contents, regardless of its length and keep the menubar at the bottom.

```
<style>
.main_wrapper {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:9999;
}
.image_content {
    height:90%;
    background:red;
    overflow:auto;
}
.bottom_menu {
    height:10%;
    background:blue;
}
</style>

<div class="main_wrapper">
    <div class="image_content">
        Your main content here
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_menu">
        Menu here
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, remove the red and blue colors from the divs, they are just for the testing.

Added the following image to better explain what is going on in my code -
[image]

Comment: so i understand correctly, you don't explicitly say the <bottom menu> block will be either fixed or absolute: your way is more to say i will just say that the first block, the <image> block is absolute, and then because of this, the block that follow (the menu block) will be "forced" to behave nicely , fixed at the bottom of the screen. is that it? seems great!

Comment: am really surprized thought that such a tested and commonly used framework such as Bootstrap 3 used fixed position for menus and that it is not supported on a 10% market share mobile

Comment: @Mathieu that is why I always prefer to code on my own, rather than using an already set up framework like bootstrap as I always want to be at 100% control of my code.
By the way, added that image, if that helps you. If you have any further queries, let me know :)

Edit: Damn I've made a typo over there. Regardless*.